# Call to a member function getFrontNameByRoute() on a non-object in

Tags: php, magento

I have a trouble when I install new project for magento.

```
Error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getFrontNameByRoute() on a non-object in C:\sites\www\ciklum\web\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php on line 199
```

I don't understand how to solve It.
Help please!

Comment: This [question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3595/magento-under-php-5-4-webserver-fatal-getfrontnamebyroute-on-non-object) may helps you.

Comment: Path /Library/WebServer/Documents///trunk/http/var must be writable.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work for me. Other projects works normally but one project has this problem, all permissions was changed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Tools -> Compilation` and ensure that you have this Disabled.  If not, disable it and flush cache.